# Make a plot visible in IE

Tags: python, internet-explorer, bokeh

I've been making plots in Bokeh, they work fine in Chrome, but I just get blank pages in IE.  I thought this was because my company uses IE8 by default, but we've now been upgraded to IE11 and I see the same problem.

The IE debug console reports that the page targets document mode 7, so it may be an issue with the metadata in the page header.

Is there a way to make Bokeh output plots with the correct metadata for IE?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with a Bokeh figure at work not showing in Internet Explorer, but the figure worked fine in other browsers.

For me the problem seemed to be that intranet sites were shown in Compatability View (I must admit I don't know what Compatability View means...). The fix was to choose the options icon in the upper right corner, then `Compatibility View Settings` and then remove the checkmark at `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View`. After close and reload the figure appeared.

Answer (score 1):

We regularly test on IE before release, so I am not sure what the issue could be. You can definitely get just the plot components using various functions in `bokeh.embed` and template them into what whatever larger documents you like, but perhaps the default template needs updating or tweaking. I don't know what "document mode 7" is, but some of the other devs might be more familiar with IE and can help investigate. In any case I encourage you to make a proper issue not the GitHub issue tracker:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: Okay, maybe it's something to do with our company IE options.  I'll raise an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this issue with IE11.

I fixed it by removing `webgl=True` option from `bokeh.plotting.figure()` call.

cf. [http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/webgl.html]